# Selecting elements against a dynamic set of values in cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

It's possible to execute `cy.elements('edge[direction = "'+ direction +'"]')` to dynamically select according to the value of a variable, but is it possible to have cytoscape recognize collections of values?

I'm looking for something like:

`var validTypes = ['a','c'];
cy.elements('node[type = validTypes]')`

which would select nodes of any number of types specified in validTypes, like the functionality of a discrete mapper.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use selectors in your stylesheet:

`cy.$('node[foo = "bar"], node[foo = "baz"]')`

See http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/#selectors

Comment: It came down to something like this, I ended up writing a loop which build a long selector string from the values in an array.  Thanks for the reply @maxkfranz